# NLC training data loaded via the api is not visible from the toolkit

Tags: ibm-watson, watson, nl-classifier

I have loaded a set of training data via the NLC api and I do not see the classes as options in the training UI that is available through blue mix. Also, the queries that I have sent through the API are not showing up as being apart of the possible set of training data. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking at the same classifier id on the same Natural Language Classifier set of credentials?

Comment: Yes, I am positive. I have uploaded the files with the same user/password credentials and do not see the trained classes.